# Making mailer functions more DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, dry, mailer

Inside a mailer file, I have 11 methods all of which start with the line

```
@reservation = reservation
```

Is there a way to make this DRY? I tried the following:

```
def set_reservation
  @reservation = reservation
end
```

and then

```
before_action :set_reservation
```

Unfortunately, this always gave me something along these lines:

```
AgentReservationMailer#send_reserve_complete_mail: processed outbound mail in 1.7ms
NameError: undefined local variable or method `reservation' for #<AgentReservationMailer:0x007ffc9ae5bb38>
```

I'm still a very junior level developer, but I would like to try and make things look as professional as I can - is what I am trying to do even possible though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the error is that the mailer does not know of a variable `reservation` inside the `set_reservation` method. I'm assuming that the 11 methods you mention, which use the

```
@reservation = reservation
```

take `reservation` as an argument. As it stands, there really is no need to try and reduce duplication.

As a side note, DRY is not a principle you should follow blindly. If you had a couple of lines that were the same in each method, then that would indeed justify an ["extract method"](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring. But replacing that `@reservation = reservation` assignment with e.g. a method call `set_reservation(reservation)`, you'd still end up repeating one line across all methods.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after realizing that no `before_action` would be possible here. You are absolutely right about reservation being arguments for every method.

Thanks :-)